# What are the Pros & Cons of VPN server behind or in front of firewall?

Tags: firewalls, vpn

What are the pros and cons of a VPN server behind or in front of the firewall? There seems to be no right or wrong in either option.

An example of the VPN server in front of the firewall:

[image]

Comment: The pros and cons will have to depend on why you have the VPN in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think that would depend if the VPN server is in a public, untrusted network (as shown) or in a network behind another firewall (not shown on the drawing). 
If the VPN server was on a public network the only benefit of the VPN would be encrypting the traffic between the client and server. The tunnel traffic would still have to be considered untrusted by the shown firewall. Plus the VPN server would be exposed to attack.

It would make more sense to me to place the VPN server behind the shown firewall or in a DMZ behind another firewall (not shown), depending on the level of trust you place on the pcs connecting through the tunnels.